# get full filename

Tags: c#

I have a path "C:\Users\Web References"

Under the "Web References" folder, i have *.wsdl file

I want to get the full filename of the *.wsdl file

Thanks!

Comment: From the IDE, Explorer? What version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\Web References", "*.wsdl", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will return a collection of files - there could be more than one wsdl file in the directory. Take the first:

```
var wsdlFile = files.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that no-one is mentioning it: [`Path.GetFullPath()`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find it:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.wsdl");
```

and now `files` will contain full paths to all WSDL files (if any) in `path`.

Comment: And then he can use `Path.GetFileName(string)` to get the filename (without any substring-indexOf magic *shudders* (not that you suggested it, just saying)).

Answer (score 0):

```
// find files by filter
var result = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\Web References\\", "*.wsdl");
//if you have only one file
return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(result[0]); // "my.wsdl"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class will help you extract just the filename from a file path:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Web References";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.wsdl");

foreach (string filePath in files) {
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath); // e.g. myFile.wsdl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or using linq

```
var files = from f in Directory.GetFiles((@"C:\Users\Web References")
    where f.EndsWith(".wsdl")
    select f;

foreach (var file in files)
  ...
```